# Merge two text files into scv file

Tags: python, csv

[There are two list of words in german and english languages and each one word from one list is a translate of one another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFcMf.png)

**Please click on the link to see them.**

So, the thing is I need to convert those lists in one csv file with two columns, let's say ('de' and 'en')

But I know **I need a list for each one pair of words** and also I need to **append each one of those list in one big list, *as in the following code.*** (and I don't know how to do it) (plis help) Thanks and feel free to ask for any additional information.

```
import csv  
    
# field names  
fields = ['Name', 'Branch', 'Year', 'CGPA']  
    
# data rows of csv file 
# "rows" list contains lists with values for each field.
rows = [ ['Nikhil', 'COE', '2', '9.0'],  
         ['Sanchit', 'COE', '2', '9.1'],  
         ['Aditya', 'IT', '2', '9.3'],  
         ['Sagar', 'SE', '1', '9.5'],  
         ['Prateek', 'MCE', '3', '7.8'],  
         ['Sahil', 'EP', '2', '9.1']]
```

Also you can use pandas but another answer that was given to me didn't show me how to automate the whole process.
import pandas as pd

```
# Data as rows: 
d = [ ['schauen', 'to see'], ['Ich', 'Me']]
pd.DataFrame(d,columns="German","English"]).to_csv("words.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first you would open the first file in python, save it in a list. Then open the second file in python, save it in a list. Assuming both files have the same number of words or lines.

```
    englishWords =[]
    germanWords=[]
    f = open("english.txt", "r")
    for x in f:
      englishWords.append(x)

    f = open("german.txt", "r")
    for x in f:
      germanWords.append(x)

    data =[]
    for i in range(len(germanWords)):
      data.append([englishWords[i],germanWords[i])

    pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["German","English"]).to_csv("words.csv")
```